# Installing keras, TensorFlow2 on MacBook Air with Apple M1 Chip

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, keras, apple-m1

I recently bought a MacBook Air with the Apple M1 chip, and I'm trying to install keras for Python 3.9.10 (installed using homebrew). Using the command

```
pip3 install keras
```

in the terminal, I get the following output:

```
Collecting keras
  Using cached keras-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: keras

Successfully installed keras-2.8.0
```

Next, I entered the following series of commands (find output included as well):

```
~ % python3
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 11:40:53)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
```

After running the last line (`import keras`), I got the following output in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import tf2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

My understanding was that keras is built on top of TensorFlow, however this seems to indicate that I need TensorFlow installed on my computer as well. Is this correct? Or is there something else I'm missing?

I've heard that TensorFlow can be very difficult to install on Apple M1 computers, so I've been trying to avoid doing so, but if I do need to, how should I go about it?

Thank you ahead of time.

**UPDATE:**

I decided to try and install TensorFlow2 in the terminal using the command

```
pip3 install tf2
```

and got the following output:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tf2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tf2
```

I guess this is where the difficulty starts... is there any straightforward way to install TensorFlow2 on an Apple M1 computer? I'd really prefer not to switch compilers or anything as I don't have a great deal of experience with macOS and don't want to make any irreversible mistakes.

Thank you again.

**UPDATE 2:**

I just tried the command

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

and I got the following output:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Thank you to Dr. Snoopy for pointing out that the package was called `tensorflow` and not `tf2`. I've read the problem might have something to do with a missing multi-threading file or something, but still can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: The package is called tensorflow, not tf2.

Comment: I'm running Anaconda on my 2021 Macbook Pro with an M1 chip.  I create Jupyter notebooks in PyCharm enterprise.  I've been able to install and run Tensorflow 2, Kera, Scikit Learn, and other packages.

Comment: @duffymo thank you for your response. Did you have any trouble installing TensorFlow 2? If not, did you use pip in terminal? Or did you do it through Anaconda? Sorry for all the questions, looking for any help I can get. Thank you again.

Comment: No, Anaconda managed it without any effort on my part.  That's why I went in that direction.  Python package management is a bit of a nightmare.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll look into using Anaconda instead of managing the packages myself, anything that makes the process easier.

Comment: @duffymo I have installed Anaconda in my M1 machine. But it doesn't come with tensorflow. How did you manage to install it?

Comment: Once I had the Anaconda environment set up I'd open the Anaconda web page, choose my environment, and start adding packages: TensorFlow, Pandas, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tested method using `conda`:

- Ensure you upgrade `Mac OS X` > 12.3. [image]
- Install XCode CLI tools

```
xcode-select --install
```

- Install [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge). I prefer installing using brew

```
brew install miniforge
```

- Create a conda environment and activate it

```
conda create --name tensyflow python=3.8
conda activate tensyflow
```

- Install Tensorflow-MacOS

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
pip install tensorflow-macos # or pip3
```